# How to detect onMouseOver on underlying element in React using its boundaries

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent, event-bubbling

Can't detect an `onMouseOver` event on an element underneath a `<canvas />` that detects `onMouseMove`.

I have the `<canvas />` that has a particle simulation which depends on the `onMouseMove` event. I also have a `<div />` that lies underneath the `<canvas />`. I need to  detect its `onMouseOver` within its boundaries. I currently passed the `onMouseOver` from the wrapper `<div />` that wraps `<canvas />` and `<div />` but it results in `handleMouseOver()` for `<div />` being triggered whenever mouse is over a wrapper.

**Structure**

```
<Wrapper>
  <canvas width="100%" height="100%" z-index="2" />
  <div width="20px" height="20px" z-index="1" />
</Wrapper>
```

**Live example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/underneath-event-demo-4uzm0

My task is to catch the `onMouseOver` for the `<div />` that lies underneath the `<canvas />` that catches all the events and needs to catch the `onMouseMove` event too. `pointer-events: none` is not a solution because I need my `<canvas />` to catch events too. Changing `z-index` results in one of the elements not been available for an event catching.

Comment: plrase share component js and html as well

Comment: @NagaSaiA edited my post with an example

Comment: did you try changing z-index of Block div to 3 , I think it captures block enter and canvas move as well

Comment: @NagaSaiA It actually doesn't solve the problem: hovering over a Block fires the `onMouseEnter` for the Block only

Comment: @moshyfarm, on mouse hover of block , you are expecting the canvas move as well?

Comment: @NagaSaiA I don't expect my `<canvas />` to move. I want it to receive the `onMouseMove`  to handle particles on it while `<Block />` receives its `onMouseEnter` event. `<canvas />` itself is static. on `<Block />` hover (on `<Block />` enter actually) I want it to receive the `onMouseEnter` event so I can trigger some change only for `<Block />` while `<canvas />` still revives its `onMouseMove`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195635/discussion-between-naga-sai-a-and-moshyfawn).

Comment: Adding CanvasMousemove to block will it work , <Block onMouseEnter={handleBlockMouseMove} onMouseMove={handleCanvasMouseMove}/>, as you know that block will be inside canvas

Comment: @NagaSaiA No, it doesn't help. How should it?

Comment: <Block onMouseEnter={handleBlockMouseMove} onMouseMove={handleCanvasMouseMove}/>  with z-index of block as 3 , you will be getting console log of both "block enter" and "canvas enter" as there are two events on block now

Comment: @NagaSaiA Isn't this method a hack and doesn't actually provide the `onMouseMove` event to `<canvas />`? I need something like "pointer-events: none" which allows events to fire on the elements underneath but saving an ability to fire events on the `<canvas />` too by not canceling interaction. You gave an example where I just use `handleCanvasMouseMove` via `<Block />`. This event needs to be fired by `<canvas />`

Answer (score 0):

### You can do this

handleCanvasMouseMove

```
const handleCanvasMouseMove = e => {
    console.log("Canvas move event");
    console.log("Canvas value X", e.clientX);
    console.log("Canvas value Y", e.clientY);
  };
```

call like this

```
<Canvas onMouseMove={e => handleCanvasMouseMove(e)} />
```

Comment: How does it help with the underneath `<div />` getting its onMouseEnter event?